# Unity change the color over life times gradient in particle system in runtime;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gradient, particle-system

I'm working on a game that needs to control `ParticleSystem` in runtime.
But the problem is that I can't change the `ParticleSystem / ColorOverLifetime / Gradient` in runtime and with scripts. Here is my code to do that which didn't worked :

```
    ParticleSystem.ColorOverLifetimeModule col = backgroundParticleSystem.colorOverLifetime;

    Gradient gradient = new Gradient();
    GradientColorKey[] colorKeys = new GradientColorKey[2];
    GradientAlphaKey[] alphaKeys = new GradientAlphaKey[1];

    colorKeys[0].color = backgroundParticleStartColor;
    colorKeys[0].time = 0f;

    colorKeys[1].color = backgroundColor;
    colorKeys[1].time = 1f;

    alphaKeys[0].alpha = 1f;
    alphaKeys[0].time = 0f;

    gradient.SetKeys(colorKeys, alphaKeys);

    ParticleSystem.MinMaxGradient gr = col.color;
    gr.gradient = gradient;
```

In this code I just tried to change the gradient by remaking a new one each time and resetting its `ColorKey`s and `AlphaKey`s .

I'm sure that the gradient is setted correctly but somehow the particle system isn't updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your last two lines are the issue. Shouldn't it be

```
col.color = gradient;
```

instead like in the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem-colorOverLifetime.html)?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer it was so helpful and it fixed my issue.